# JS/jQuery do something on file create

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to trigger an event when file is created in some directory? Similar to jquery `click` function, I want to have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(this).fileCreated(function() {....}
});
```

I'll need to react to RF card reader, which will store data to file, and this solution (if it is possible ofc) would probably be the easiest to implement.

I'll need this for a web service whivh will only run locally with no access to source code or anything. Security shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: Is this for a website?  I believe as a security measure the browser won't have access to the nitty-gritty of the host filesystem...

Comment: Javascript writing files to file system will be a huge security risk. I dont think anyone would want that.

Comment: Are you going to create a file in the browser?

Comment: It will be a web service which will only run locally with no access to source code or anything. Security shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: If your javascript code runs in the browser then you cannot listen to file changes done on your local machine because this is would be security issue. If you run you code in electron or similar then it would be possible. Or you card reader has to implement a small webserver with an http based api.

Comment: Yep you are right, it would be stupid to implement something that would be a security risk almost everytime. Does anyone else knows how to implement connection between a file that was created by a RF card reader and web page?

Answer (score 0):

@t.niese Pointed out my bad solution.

After reconsidering the issue I would likely have an on click listener in which the callback checked to see if the file path for the new file was to the directory of concern before doing anything else. That way you could also make functions for future paths using the same listener and callback function if you wanted.

Recognizing you want the listener to focus on actual file creation I double checked on JS events and found onsubmit as the closest to what you're looking for, but it appears to simply work similarly to on click anyway.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit

If a request is being made by your application after reading an RF card I don't see why you couldn't use .ready if you incorporate it into some html response.

The only other possibility I can see would be to find some framework that expands on available events. I know [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) does some extra stuff with events.